# Using esky with GUI program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, distutils, esky

I have a GUI program written in python and packaged with `py2exe`. I now want to use `Esky` to allow automatic updating.

However when I'm running`python setup.py bdist_esky`, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: don't call setup(windows=[...]) with esky; use setup(scripts=[...]) instead
```

When changing to `scripts`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Must specify name if script is not a file
```

I cant manage to get rid of it. Any help?

(setup.py: http://pastebin.com/B3yGJERq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts is supposed to be a list of `esky.bdist_esky.Exectuable` instances.

Here is code example: http://mastr-ms.googlecode.com/hg-history/39af8165be80344a30603e0ff74acdded72193b0/madas/mdatasync_client/client/setup.py